# $\limsup$ of Images of collection of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{A_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ be a collection of Lebesgue measurable sets and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda(A_j)<\infty, f(x)=x^2$ then $\lambda(\limsup f(A_j))=0$. $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

By definition, $\limsup f(A_j)=\{y \mid y \in f(A_j) \ \text{for  infinitely  many} \ j\}$. Since each $A_j$ is lebesgue measurable, they are of the form $A_j=E_j \cup N_j$ where $E_j$ is borel, and $N_j$ is null. Since $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda(A_j)<\infty$, we may assume that the nonull parts of $A_j$ are bounded (Here I mean if one of the $A_i$'s is unbounded, the part that is unbounded has measure zero). Let $y \in f(A_j)$ for some $j$. Since $|f^{-1}(\{y\})|\leq 2$ for each $y$, and $\{A_j\}$ is infinite, we must have each $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ are contained in only finitely many sets of positive measure. Since this holds for any $y \in \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}f(A_j)$, we see that any point in the set is contained in only finitely many sets of positive measure so that $\lambda(\limsup f(A_j))=0$.

I have tried this problem several times and have been unsuccessful each time. Is this the correct way to do this? Also, my "proof" does not seem rigorous enough. How to make this more rigorous?

Edit: I see there is a major flaw in this attempt. I cannot assume anything about the boundedness of the $A_i$'s. How should I take another approach to this?

Comment: Do you suppose that $\lambda$ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @BotnakovN. yes

Comment: Boundedness cannot be assumed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how should I proceed to do this?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ but is not bounded.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I meant assume the nonnull parts are bounded. But I do not know if that makes sense. Can you help me start this problem in the right direction?

Comment: @Rene $\bigcup_n (q_n - 1/n^2, q_n + 1/n^2)$ where $\{q_n\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals is unbounded but has finite measure.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis OK I understand now, there is a major flaw in this attempt. Can you help me get off to the right start? All I need is a hint. This is not an assignment I am preparing for a test with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in \lim \sup f(A_n)$. Then we can write $y=x_n^{2}$ with $x _n \in A_n$ for infinitely many values of $n$. But then $\pm \sqrt y \in A_n$ for infinitely many values of $n$ which implies either $ \sqrt y \in A_n$ for infinitely many values of $n$ or $- \sqrt y \in A_n$ for infinitely many values of $n$. But $\sum \lambda (A_n) <\infty$ implies that $\lim \sup A_n$ has measure $0$. So there is a set $E$ such that $\lambda (E)=0$ and $\pm \sqrt y \in E$ whenever $y \in \lim \sup f(A_n)$. Can you finish the proof now?

Answer (score 2):

Put $B_n = A_n \cup (-A_n)$. We have $$y \in \overline{\lim} f(A_j) \Rightarrow \big(\forall N \exists n \ge N: y \in f(A_n) \big) \Rightarrow $$ $$\big( \forall N \exists n \ge N \exists x_n \in A_n: x_n^2 = y\big) \Rightarrow \big(  \forall N \exists n \ge N \exists x_n \in A_n: x_n = \pm \sqrt{y} \big) $$ $$\Rightarrow \big( \forall N \exists n \ge N: (\sqrt{y} \in A_n) \vee (\sqrt{y} \in - A_n)\big)$$ $$\Rightarrow \big( \forall N \exists n \ge N: \sqrt{y} \in B_n \big) \Rightarrow  \sqrt{y} \in \overline{\lim}  B_n.$$
But $\lambda(B_n) =\lambda(A_n \cup (-A_n)) \le  \lambda(A_n) + \lambda(-A_n) = 2 \lambda(A_n)$ and hence $\sum_n \lambda(B_n) < \infty$. Put $C = \overline{\lim}  B_n$. It follows from Borel–Cantelli Lemma for measure spaces that $\lambda(C) = 0$.

So we proved that $y \in  \overline{\lim} f(A_j) \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} \in C$ and $\lambda(C) = 0$. It follows that $\lambda(\overline{\lim} f(A_j)) = 0$.

Addition:
**Lemma**. If $\lambda(C) = 0$ and $\big( y \in B \Rightarrow \sqrt{y} \in C \big) $ then $\lambda(B) = 0$.

Proof.
Note that $y \in B \Rightarrow  \sqrt{y}  \exists   \Rightarrow B \subset [0,+\infty)$. Consider $B^* = B \cap (a,b)$ for some positive $a, b > 0$. It's sufficient to show that $\lambda(B^*) = 0$. We know that $\sqrt{B^*} \subset C$. In other words, $g(B^*) \subset C$ where $g$ is strictly increasing, $0 < C_1 \le g' \le C_2 < \infty$ and $g'$ is continious. It's sufficient to use lemma 2.

**Lemma 2**.
If $\lambda(C) = 0$ and $g(B^*) \subset C$ where $0 < C_1 \le g' \le C_2 < \infty$ and $g'$ is continious. Then $\lambda(B^*) = 0$.
Hint to the proof: we may consider sets $D_j$ from definition of outer measure of $C$ and take $g^{-1}(D_j)$.

Comment: I am really sorry I have such trouble with my understanding. Can you please explain why the last sentence holds.

Comment: @Rene, I made and addition.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.